# Uncaught TypeError adding chart in markdown using Jekyll

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, markdown, jekyll

I'm trying to add a chart to my markdown blog post (using jekyll) and am running into problems getting the scripts to be recognized when serving the site locally.

I just add the necessary scripts to in my .md file (in the beginning):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/highcharts/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

These are being loaded no problem, and if for instance I remove highcharts.js, highcharts-more.js throws a ReferenceError because it depends on highcharts.js. So far so good. However, when further down the line I use the $(...).highcharts() function I get following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function
```

If I check the sources in Chrome console, I see highcharts was loaded...

So I assume somehow the later script calling highcharts runs before highcharts is loaded. I don't understand this at all :). Please help!

Full code:

```
---
layout: post
title: "De geschiedenis van de eerste klasse."
categories: [posts,random]
utilities: highlight
---
<script src="https://gist.github.com/yizeng/2371e8b83c9254ed77f2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/highcharts/highcharts-more.js"></script> 

<script src="https://rawgit.com/highslide-software/pattern-fill/master/pattern-fill.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/custom.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   <!--Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="/assets/js/moment/moment.js"></script>

<script>
  elo_evolution = {{ site.data.elo-evolution | jsonify }}
  max_elo_data ={{ site.data.max_elo_data | jsonify}}
  dates = {{site.data.dates| jsonify}}
  teams = {{site.data.teams| jsonify}}
  seasons = {{site.data.seasons| jsonify}}
</script>

<script>
  function max() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return Math.max.apply(Math, args.filter(function(val) {
       return !isNaN(val);
    }));
}

  function drawEloChart(team_select) {
  // series = data that will be shown (dates & elo)
  series = []
  for (i=0;i<seasons.length;i++) {
      data = []
      for (j=0;j<elo_evolution[team_select][seasons[i]][0].length;j++) {
          data.push([elo_evolution[team_select][seasons[i]][0][j],elo_evolution[team_select][seasons[i]][1][j]])
      }
      series.push({name:seasons[i],data:data, marker: {symbol: "circle"} })
  }

  // Max ELO opmaak
  for(i=0;i < max_elo_data[team_select].length;i++) {
      series[max_elo_data[team_select][i][0]].data[max_elo_data[team_select][i][1]] = { marker: {
                                                                                          symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)',
                                                                                          enabled: true,
                                                                                          fillColor: '#FF0000',
                                                                                          lineWidth: 0.2,
                                                                                          radius: 2,
                                                                                          lineColor: "#FF0000" // inherit from series
                                                                                  },y:series[max_elo_data[team_select][i][0]].data[max_elo_data[team_select][i][1]][1],x: series[max_elo_data[team_select][i][0]].data[max_elo_data[team_select][i][1]][0]}
  }

   $('#container').highcharts({
       chart: {
           type: 'spline',
           zoomType: 'x',
           plotBackgroundImage: 'http://i.imgur.com/9ePWdzK.png',
          // renderTo: 'container',
          // Fancy stuff here
          events: {
              selection: function (event) {
                  if (event.xAxis) {
                      // Zoom
                      // alert(this.options)
                      this.options.plotBackgroundImage= ""
                      this.redraw()
                      // this.chart.options.plotBackgroundImage='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/Roses_renoir.JPG';
                      // this.chart
                      // text = 'min: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(event.xAxis[0].min, 2) + ', max: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(event.xAxis[0].max, 2);
                  } else {
                      // Reset zoom
                  }
              }
          }
      },
       credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
      // chart: {
      //     type: 'spline'
      // },
      title: {
          text: 'ELO Rating Jupiler Pro League Ploegen'
      },
      subtitle: {
          text: 'Een analyse van 20 jaar JPL.'
      },
      xAxis: {
          // events: {
          //     afterSetExtremes: function() {
          //     // Na Zoom, geen background image meer.
          //     }
          // },
          type: 'datetime',
          // dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
          //     month: '%e. %b',
          //     year: '%Y'
          // },
          // title: {
          //     text: 'Date'
          // },
          // labels: {
          //     format: "{value:%Y-%m-%d}"
          // },
          min: dates[0],
          max: dates[dates.length - 1],
          labels: {
                  formatter: function() {
                      if ((moment(this.value).year()-1)%5 == 0) {
                           date_string = String(moment(this.value).year()-1) + "/" + String(moment(this.value).year())
                      } else {
                          date_string = ""
                      }

                      return date_string;
                  }            
          },

      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'ELO Rating'
          },
          min: 1100,
          max: 2000,
          labels: {
              formatter: function() {
                      if (this.value == 1500) {
                          y_label = "<strong>GEM</strong>"
                      }
                      else {
                          y_label = this.value
                      }

                  return y_label;
              }  
          }
      },
      tooltip: {

          formatter: function () {
              var s = '<table><td colspan="2" style="text-align: center"><strong>' + this.y + '</strong></td>'
              gameday_index = this.series.data.indexOf(this.point)


              s += '<tr><td class="tooltip-elo-one" style="text-align: right"><b>' + elo_evolution[team_select][this.series.name][2][gameday_index]   + '</b></td></tr>' +  
              '<td class="tooltip-elo-one" style="text-align: right"><b>' + elo_evolution[team_select][this.series.name][3][gameday_index]   + '</b></td></tr>' + 

              // Datum
              '<tr>' +
              '<td colspan="2" class="tooltip-elo-one" style="text-align: right"><b>' + moment(this.x).calendar()  + '</b></td></tr>'

                          // elo_evolution[team][this.series.name][3] +


                  s += '</table>'
              // });


              return s;
          },

          useHTML: true,
      },

      plotOptions: {
          spline: {
              marker: {
                  enabled: false,
                  states: {
                      hover: {
                          enabled: true
                      }
                  }
              },
              color: 'rgb(50,50,50)',
              showInLegend: false
          }
      },

      series: series
  });
};
</script>
  <script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {

      for (i = 0;i<teams.length;i++) {
          if (teams[i] == "Anderlecht") {
              // $("#dropdown").append('<option><a id="team_' +String(i) +'" href="#" onclick="clickTeam(this.id);return false;">' +
              //                              '<img class="floatLeft" src="/assets/images/posts/Team Logos/' + teams[i] + '.png"' +  'height="20" width="20" />' +
              //                              '&nbsp;' + teams[i] + '</a></option>')

              $("#dropdown_list").append('<li><a id="team_' +String(i) +'" href="#" onclick="clickTeam(this.id);return false;">' +
                                          '<img class="floatLeft" src="/assets/images/posts/Team Logos/' + teams[i] + '.png"' +  'height="20" width="20" />' +
                                          '&nbsp;' + teams[i] + '</a></li>'
                  )

              var team_select = teams[i]
              var team_count = i
              $("#button_list").html(teams[i] + '  &nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>')

          } else  {
                              // $("#dropdown").append('<option><a id="team_' +String(i) +'" href="#" onclick="clickTeam(this.id);return false;">' +
                              //              '<img class="floatLeft" src="/assets/images/posts/Team Logos/' + teams[i] + '.png"' +  'height="20" width="20" />' +
                              //              '&nbsp;' + teams[i] + '</a></option>')
              $("#dropdown_list").append('<li><a id="team_' +String(i) +'" href="#" onclick="clickTeam(this.id);return false;">' +
                                          '<img class="floatLeft" src="/assets/images/posts/Team Logos/' + teams[i] + '.png"' +  'height="20" width="20" />' +
                                          '&nbsp;' + teams[i] + '</a></li>'
                  )
          }

      }
      drawEloChart(team_select);
});
</script>

<div class="btn-group text-center" role="group">

<button id="button_list" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Kies team&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>

<ul id= "dropdown_list" class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
</ul>

</div>


  <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>



{% highlight ruby %}
def foo
  puts 'foo'
end
{% endhighlight %}




{% highlight javascript linenos=table %}
function myFunction() {
    alert("Hello World!");
}
{% endhighlight %}
```

Function drawEloChart is called at the end of the `$( document ).ready(function()` script. drawEloChart then calls highcharts, and that is where the error occurs.

Comment: could you please provide jsfiddle?

Comment: you should check that another ```jquery.js``` library not loaded after you loads ```highcharts.js```

Comment: Make sure you are creating chart **after** page is loaded (`onload` event). Also, make sure you are using latest version of highcharts. And of course, check if paths are proper for all files.

Comment: @AlexFilatov that might be it! How do I make sure all my scripts are loaded only after the standard layout scripts (which contain jquery) are loaded?

Comment: See first line in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4okzs960/ - chart is created inside jQuery callback: `$(function () { ... })`.

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't fix it.

OK I'm going insane here. Code works fine outside jekyll, so I'm pretty confident the issue is what @AlexFilatov said: my jquery library is loaded before highcharts, and after that the jquery library of the jekyll template code is loaded, breaking higcharts (for some reason). However, if my hypothesis is correct the following fix should work:

load highcharts inside $( document ).ready(function() by calling $.getScript('/assets/js/highcharts/highcharts.js'); 

And it doesn't. Thanks in advance for your help guys!

Comment: can you drop you code in a github repository ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel https://github.com/exergos/jekyll-highcharts-problem , everything is in the blog map. I've put the code that call highcharts in a separate js, voetbalelo.js.  The blog I wanna post is: 2015-06-02-voetbal-elo.md . Thanks!

Comment: I see that I left the script that loads voetbalelo.js as a comment, changed that now. The error is now: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

The problem was that jQuery is loaded AFTER highcharts.js, generating the `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function` issue.

I tried to fix it by loading highcharts.js like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
       $.getScript(".../highcharts.js");
});
```

However, in my case this doesn't load highcharts.js on time for the execution of the code that calls the highcharts function, generating the issue.

To fix this and making it run on time use "async: false":

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: ".../highcharts.js",
        dataType: 'script',
        async: false
      });
  });
```

Thanks to everyone for the help!